# Using async await in map with a join

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I am using vanilla js to create a spa and I have hit an issue with using async-await with maps. 
My page is like this;

```
render: async () => {
    let result = await getPostsList()
    if (result.status == "success") {
        let posts = result.data
        let view =  /*html*/`
        <section class="section pageEntry">
            <h1> Home </h1>

            <div class="columns is-multiline" id="cards_container">
            ${await Promise.all(posts.map( (post) => Card.render(post)).join('\n ')) }
            </div>
        </section>
        `
        return view
    } else {
        console.log(result)
    }
```

and the child component is;

```
 render: async (post) => {
        // console.log(post)
        let view =  /*html*/`                
            <div class="column is-half">
                <article class="media">
                    <figure class="media-left">
                        <p class="image is-128x128">
                        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
                        </p>
                    </figure>
                    <div class="media-content">
                        <div class="content">
                        <p>
                            ${post.title}
                            <strong>${post.author}</strong> <small>@johnsmith</small> <small>31m</small>
                            <br>
                            ${post.content}
                        </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                </article>
            </div>
        `
        return view
```

I understand that to use async-await with map, i should use a Promise.all. However, on doing that i get commas between my individual components. 
[image]

If I use a .join('') to remove the commas, it is then giving me a completely weird output. If I try join with async-await in maps, I get something like

[image]

Comment: Since you await result, result, data should not be promises anymore, so just try mapping instead of Promise.all().

Comment: I started without Promise.all My Ui just showed `[object Promise][object Promise][object Promise][object Promise] `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  await a().b()
```

awaits the result of the `b` property call.

```
 (await a()).b()
```

awaits `a` and then calls `b()` on the result. Additionally you call `join` directly on the array of promises:

```
posts.map( (post) => Card.render(post)).join('\n ')
```

You want to call it on the awaited result. All in all:

```
 const rendered = await Promise.all(posts.map( (post) => Card.render(post));

 return `... ${rendered.join("\n")} ...`
```